# Postfix is ignoring the virtual maps

Tags: postfix

I am using Postfix and when I try to send an email to a virtual address (paradise@example.org), it is not able to find the user:

```
Aug  7 11:55:32 example postfix/local[24435]: AE54C808E546: to=<paradise@example.org>, relay=local, delay=6.6, delays=4.8/0.47/0/1.4, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "paradise")
```

I am using the following virtual map:

```
paradise@example.org horus
@example.org horus
```

Where horus is my (non-root) Unix user. If I try to verify the virtual addres by doing:

```
postmap -q paradise@example.org hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

It returns my current user:

```
horus
```

Because of that, I am not sure why is not able to find paradise@example.org or paradise.

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = example.org,localhost
myhostname = example.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = example.org
readme_directory = no
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

And my /etc/aliases (but as far as I know, it is used only for local delivery) is:

```
...
www:            webmaster
webmaster:      root
noc:            root
security:       root
hostmaster:     root
info:           postmaster
marketing:      postmaster
sales:          postmaster
support:        postmaster


# trap decode to catch security attacks
decode:         root

# Person who should get root's mail
root:           horus
```

The database seems to be okay:

> db_dump /etc/postfix/virtual.db -p

```
VERSION=3
format=print
type=hash
h_nelem=4098
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
paradise@example.org\00
horus\00
@example.org\00
horus\00
DATA=END
```

What is wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `virtual_alias_maps` to deliver mail, you must also tell Postfix which domains it should consult the map for, with the [`virtual_alias_domains`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains) directive. This can be a plain list of domains, or it can also be one of the map types Postfix supports.

```
virtual_alias_domains = example.org
```

will get you going, and you can put in a map or whatever you want later.

See also the [Postfix documentation on virtual hosting](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html).

Answer (score 2):

Did you run:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
postfix reload
```

Comment: Yes, and /etc/postfix/virtual.db exists.